# posix thread synchronization stop at same code

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, posix

I have multiple threads, and I want each thread to wait for every others to complete at certain point in the code before proceeding as following:

```
void *run() { 
  for (i=0;i<1000;i++){
    do_1st();
    // sync() all stop here wait for all then resume
    do_2nd();
  }
}
```

I tried to use pthread_cond_wait.. but It seems very complicated.

Is there any easy wait to do this ?

Thank you

Comment: barrier answer is correct, but you can also consider using the boost wrappers for ease-of-use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [pthread_barrier](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html), initialize it before you start your threads, and set the `count` to the no. of threads that's running your loop. e.g. if you have 8 threads:

```
pthread_barrier_init(&my_barrier,NULL,8);
```

The thread loop now becomes

```
void *run() { 
  for (i=0;i<1000;i++){
    do_1st();
    pthread_barrier_wait(&my_barrier);
    do_2nd();
  }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I need ! thx nos. btw do i need to destroy the barrier after used ?

Comment: You should, yes - though if you're running your threads in several batches, you can reuse it. If your application exits when you're done with those calculations, it'll be cleaned up on process exit.